# How to manipulate a file descriptor in another process?

Tags: files, process, proc, file-descriptors, access-control

Is there any way to manipulate (read, write, etc..) a file descriptor for any app which can be found in the path `/proc/{pid}/fd`?

Especially for sockets.

```
$ ll /proc/4229/fd
total 0
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 0 -> socket:[34147]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 1 -> socket:[34149]
lr-x------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 10 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 11 -> socket:[34943]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 13 -> socket:[34945]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 14 -> socket:[34948]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 15 -> socket:[34950]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 2 -> socket:[34151]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 3 -> socket:[34153]
lr-x------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 4 -> pipe:[34155]
l-wx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 5 -> pipe:[34155]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 6 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 7 -> pipe:[34156]
l-wx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 8 -> pipe:[34156]
lrwx------. 1 vagrant vagrant 64 May 18 01:10 9 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots when you can simply copy/paste text.  Text is searchable, but images are not.  Remote images can also disappear over time.

Comment: @garethTheRed you are right, done.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, almost anything is possible with `ptrace()` / `gdb`.  [Search results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ptrace+OR+gdb+steal+copy+of+fd).

Using `ptrace()` is arch-dependent, awkward, and AFAICT no-one's implemented it for you.  The popular application is to inject an fd into the process, but that's about the opposite of what you want.

I thought about what would be required and it looks very painful.

You could use the gdb script approach, and look at the source code of [screenify](http://sooda.dy.fi/foo/screenify).  It's probably still very awkward to communicate FDs from within gdb.  The way you communicate fds is to send them as "ancillary data" using `sendmsg()` over a unix socket.

Unfortunately sending ancillary data is usually done using a macro.  While `gdb` does an amazing impression of a C interpreter, I don't think it's possible to use macros.

The other way you pass fds is using `fork()`, so that might provide some slightly easier options (combined with `exec()`).  Unfortunately it looks like `ptrace()` and `fork()` are not best friends.  There are some [linux-specific gdb commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) which might do the job, but it only mentions support for breakpoints; it doesn't say whether you can get the gdb command `call fork()` to work sensibly.  Even if it works, you might need to mess with `FD_CLOEXEC` (close-on-exec) as well.  That's a macro too.

It's not too hard to find the numeric value of a simple macro (that's how screenify was written).  The macro interface for sending ancillary data isn't very complicated, so it might be easier to reverse engineer that instead.